# How do I run an async function every 10 seconds in Flutter to simulate checking the user's login state?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, sql-server-2019

I have a Flutter app that runs a stored procedure in SQL Server using the [sql_conn package](https://pub.dev/packages/sql_conn). This SP will return the login state of the user. If they are suddenly restricted from being logged in, I want the Flutter app to know about this within 5 seconds.

Below is my code that calls the SP from Flutter. I now need it to run on a 5 second frequency and then handle what happens if the login state is ever 0 (logout and send user back to login screen). How would I do this?

```
void getLoginState() async {
    await sqlConnect();

    var res = await SqlConn.readData("declare @LoginState bit declare @Status nvarchar(4000) exec spHandheldLogin '${userController.text}', '${passwordController.text}', @LoginState output, @Status output");

    res = json.decode(res); //Gets the first object in the list. This is fine because this SP will only ever return 1 row
    res = res[0];
    var LoginState = res['LoginState'];
    var Status = res['Status'];

    await sqlDisconnect();
}
```

Comment: I appreciate I don't know Flutter/dart, but that looks like injection to me with that syntax.

Comment: @ThomA that is a good point...hmm...not sure how to make it injection-proof here. Any ideas?

Comment: As I mentioned, I don't know Flutter/Dart, though I don't doubt there are existing questions/articles/documentation out there on how to parametrise your query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
import 'dart:async';

Timer? timer;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 10), (Timer t) => 
  getLoginState()); // Your function
}

@override
void dispose() {
  timer?.cancel();
  super.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity - would it have been possible to use a Stream here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use stream and listen to the auth changes

```
import 'dart:async';

StreamSubscription? timerSubscription;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  timerSubscription = Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 10), (int count) {
    getLoginState(); // Your function
  }).listen((event) {});
}

@override
void dispose() {
  timerSubscription?.cancel();
  super.dispose();
}
```